# turn on JavaScript in your browser to continue

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

i'm using `python3.6` on `pythonanywhere`, when i try to run pydrive *(to upload files to google drive automatically)* i get this error:-

```
You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.                               

   Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.
```

it requires me to login to my gmail account so i think that's the problem, how can i workaround this problem?

here's my entire code

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive


def uploadimg(kart, band, fraction):
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
    if gauth.credentials is None:
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        gauth.Authorize()
    # Save the current credentials to a file
    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    ######################

    file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': "lqi"+fraction+"bandi"+band+"karti"+kart})
    file1.SetContentFile("hi.jpg")
    file1.Upload()

    file3 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})

uploadimg("h","h","e")
```

Comment: how do you call `PyDrive`?

Comment: i have added my entire code

Answer (score 0):

i had to use `gauth.CommandLineAuth()` instead of `gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()` to use it on remote servers